# Is there a way to represent a multi-dimensional matrix (e.x. 3x3x3)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

Coming from a CS perspective, where you could have a multidimensional array:

`x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` would be equivalent to $x = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6 \end{pmatrix}$

Is there a way of representing a matrix with more than 2 dimensions in linear algebra? For example: `x = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]],[[9,10],[11,12]]]`

And is there a distinction made between using the term "dimensions" to refer to the number of rows and number of columns (ie "a 2x3 matrix") and using it to refer to the dimensionality of the matrix itself (ie "an m by n matrix is a 2D matrix" or "an m by n by m' by n' matrix is a 4D matrix")?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "represent"? You already wrote an example, and it's definitely a "representation". Now, if you insist in something that looks like a table like a 2-dimensional array, of course no: it's 2-dimensional. To represent 3 dimensions on a plane, you have to resort to a trick, like writing several matrices in a row to represent the 3rd dimension. But that's hardly a problem. Even with 2d matrices, we rarely need to write them down element by element.

Comment: Regarding the term to talk about dimensionality, I think it's usually [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(computer_programming)), which is arguably confusing. See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TensorRank.html (and note there is already some ambiguity when talking about rank-2 tensors (co/contra?), and think about the change of basis for a linear map or for a quadratic form, whcih are both represented by a matrix.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Sorry, to clarify, I guess I was asking how you would write a rank 3 matrix with the same notation as you would write a rank 2 matrix – with the columns and rows aligned and the large brackets. Is there an equivalent for matrices with a rank > 2 or would it be written the same way you'd write a 3-dimensional array in a programming language like python or javascript: `x = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]],[[9,10],[11,12]]]`?

Comment: I don't know of a standardized notation, but I guess it will be either a notation like the one you used, or no notation at all, and resort to tricks, like writing separately $a(1,:,:), a(2,:,:)$ and $a(3,:,:)$, or simply write $a_{ijk}=\dots$ or whatever. You obviously can't fit directly a 3-dimensional (or more) table in a 2-dimensional table. Anyway, like for matrices, it's often useless or impractical to write the elements one by one.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Okay cool, that answers my question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the dimensionality of the matrix itself as the [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(computer_programming)).

[Here's an article on TensorRank from Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TensorRank.html).

You obviously can't draw a matrix with a rank greater than 2 on paper. There isn't necessarily a standard notation but you could separate it into parts: $a(1,:,:)$, $a(2,:,:)$ and $a(3,:,:)$

or use notation like: $a_{ijk} = \ldots$

Credit to: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut